# Why is this HTML output changing?

Tags: html, css

I was playing with CSS and HTML and I'm not sure why the output changes when I add text inside a div tag.

First:

```css
div.bar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 75px;   /* We'll override height later */
    background-color: teal;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar" style="height: 15px;"></div>
<div class="bar" style="height: 20px;"></div>
<div class="bar" style="height: 25px;"></div>
<div class="bar" style="height: 30px;"></div>
```

The output is four bars.

Second:

```css
div.bar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 75px;   /* We'll override height later */
    background-color: teal;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar" style="height: 15px;">15</div>
<div class="bar" style="height: 20px;">20</div>
<div class="bar" style="height: 25px;">25</div>
<div class="bar" style="height: 30px;">30</div>
```

The output is the same but upside down.

I hope that you can tell me why.

Comment: You might want to checkout flexbox: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the default vertical alignment, `baseline`. Use `vertical-align: bottom` to fix the behaviour:

```css
    div.bar {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 75px;   /* We'll override height later */
        background-color: teal;
        margin-right: 2px;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="bar" style="height: 15px;">15</div>
    <div class="bar" style="height: 20px;">20</div>
    <div class="bar" style="height: 25px;">25</div>
    <div class="bar" style="height: 30px;">30</div>
```

Comment: Also see @JamesMontagne comment for an explanation of how `baseline` is influencing the rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Try use `vertical-align: bottom;`!

Comment: This is correct.  For a bit more detail, the default vertical alignment is `baseline`.  This aligns based on the baseline of the text.  When there is no text, it simply aligns the bottom of the boxes.  Once text is introduced, the alignment is based on the text, not the box.